# MVC 4 "Bug" Parameter Object Named "Message/message" will not be Deserialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Ran into a very strange error today in MVC. I do not want to post all my code, but I will post a small example.

Say I have a cshtml page with a form in it:

```
@model UserValidation
<!-- Code before body -->

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateUser", "Account"))
{
   <div class="Label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name):</div>
   <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)</div>
   <div style="clear: both;">
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)

   <div class="Label">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.OldPass):</div>
   <div>@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.OldPass)</div>
   <div style="clear: both;">
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.OldPass)
   <!-- More Form Code Here, You get the idea --> 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Along with a validation class (I am not sure if this is part of the issue or not)

```
public class UserValidation
{
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPass { get; set; }
    //More code here
}
```

And finially, an HTTPPOST in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateInfo(UserValidation message)
{
      //Code
      if(message == null)
      {
          return null;   //If param name == message this line is hit
      }

      return View();
}
```

If the parameter to `UpdateInfo` is "message" or "Message" (and only those from what I know of) MVC will not be able to deserialized the object and it will always equal `null`. However, if we simply change the parameter object's name it will contain the correct form data:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateInfo(UserValidation newUserInfo)
{
     //Code
     if(newUserInfo == null)
     {
         return null;   
     }
      return View(); //Param name != message, this line is hit
}
```

Again, this only occurs when the object is equal to "message" or "Message". I have no idea why this is the case.

Does anyone have a reason for this?

Comment: Maybe message is being internally used

Comment: why don't you simply use `newUserInfo` instead of keep trying to use `message`?

Comment: I tried it and it works perfect...see your model or/and view  very well if it has message or something in it

Comment: Do you have a property called `Message` on your `UserValidation` class?

Comment: I am using a newUserInfo. I am more or less curious about why this is happening. I'll have to look into my code a bit more I guess

Comment: I have `public string Message { get; set; }` in my validation class. Must be why

Comment: Yep, that is why.  I had the same problem when I was posting a model with a property "id" and my parameter to my action was "id"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have a property called `Message` on your `UserValidation` class.

This confuses the model binder because it first tries to match the posted values with the parameter names and only after that it moves to match the properties of the complex parameter types.

In your case it sees a `Message` key in your posted data so it tries to match your whole `UserValidation message` parameter which will fail so the whole binding process stops and you get the `null`.

I've only found some unofficial mentioning of this "feature":

- [Default Model Binding: ActionMethod Parameter name must not equal Model Property name?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1891799.aspx?Default%20Model%20Binding%20ActionMethod%20Parameter%20name%20must%20not%20equal%20Model%20Property%20name%20)
- [MVC3 - Model Property Name and Action Parameter Name - Fight!](https://coderwall.com/p/zmpeyw)

So just use a different parameter name and it will work fine.